# Selecting readOnly textboxes with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my ASP.NET MVC project i need to select all text boxes that have attributed "readOnly" in current page and show modal Jquery dialog in keypress on the disabled text box.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything yet?..

Just to select the elements and apply a method to the keypress you could do the following:

```
$(":text[readonly]").keypress(function() { /*do your magic*/ });
```